# Docker container not running for a simple file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
```

the above is all i have in the docker file to just install vim over ubuntu

I run this in local using

```
docker build -t myFirstUbuntuimage .
```

Then if i run the container using the above image as

```
docker run -d --name myfirstcontainer myFirstUbuntuimage:latest
```

the container does not run. How can i make it run?

docker ps shows empty

Comment: What's the `CMD` the container's supposed to run?  (Most often Docker is used with long-running server processes, and I'd consider it unusual to install a text editor in a container.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container is probably running just fine. The default behavior of the `ubuntu` image is to start an interactive shell, but since you're starting a non-interactive container, the shell will just exit immediately.

What do you *expect* to happen when you run the container?

If you drop the `-d` and add `-it`, you'll get an interactive shell:

```
docker run -it --name myfirstcontainer myFirstUbuntuimage:latest
```